# Put elements in separate lines

Tags: android

I'm trying to put `TextView`, `EdiText`, and `Button` on 3 separate lines but they end up on the same line :

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/lat_label"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/lat_label" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

I just started android, what do I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `LinearLayout` as a parent to these three view and set `android:orientation="vertical"`  to that `LinearLayout`. That's it. Simple :-)

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/lat_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/lat_label" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you had first horizontal :-P just mistake maybe.

Answer (score 1):

> Put elements in seperate lines

You need to use `android:orientation="vertical"` property for your *layout* and then you will have *element* on one line and next *element* bellow its.